# Error when using \overline inside \emph

Tags: italic, kile

I'm writing a paper in Kile, which uses LaTeX. I need to have an italicized character with a line over it. The code I'm currently using is:

```
$\emph{uuds\overline{s}}$
```

I'm getting this error:

> Missing $ inserted ...$\emph{uuds\overline{s}}

Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong? Is it possible to create an italicized character with a bar over it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\overline` works in math mode.

Comment: Is math mode \ [  ...   \ ] or can it be written any other way? Doesn't that create a new line?

Comment: `$ ... $` is math mode too! But it's in-line math mode meant for mathematics that appears inline with running text. `\[ ... \]` is for display math mode meant for equations that you want to display separately. It does create a new line

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmmm. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here.

`\emph{}` is a text mode command meant for emphasising something as part of the text, e.g.:

```
That was a \emph{really} bad idea, as it turned out.
```

By default, it uses italics for emphasis, but that's just an accident of the implementation. It could as well use bold, for example, and you could configure it to.

It is meant for text, it is a text mode command and if you use it inside `$ ... $` it puts everything inside into text mode. `$\emph{abc}$` is the same as `\emph{abc}`. Math mode commands like `\overline{s}` can't work inside text mode so that's your problem.

The next thing to say is that letters in math mode are italicised by default. Try

```
$abc$
```

What do you notice?

So all you needed was:

```
$uuds\overline{s}$
```

[image]

Though I confess myself to being a little suspicious about what *uudss̄* is precisely. Is it supposed to be a string of mathematical variables multiplied together. Or is it supposed to be italicised text? In which case you want.

```
\textit{uuds\={s}}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is italicized text - it denotes the quark composition of a particle.

Comment: It is not exactly true that `\emph` *italicises* by accident. It's just true that **bold** is too eye-catching and changes the grey value, <u>underline</u> (man underlining is hard in these comments) is a typographically speaking horrible thing to do in text, not to speak of l e t t e r s p a c i n g. It is just the objectively determined best way to emphasize something in your text.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes :) What i meant was more that there's no intrinsic and necessary link between `\emph` and italics and `\emph` is not really an alternative to `\textit`

Comment: @Au101 Especially in `\emph{\emph{text}}` this is true, as it wouldn't use italics. One could say that `\emph` and `\textit` are semantically totally different things and should never get mixed up.

Comment: Too late to u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲ that u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲ in my first comment :(

Answer (score 2):

if this is really a "text" string, perhaps the text overbar would suffice:

[image: output of example code]

this is produced by

```
\emph{uuds\=s}
```